# Storing Tile Data In Excess of 100 Million Tiles Per Layer Multiple Layers

Tags: c++, c++11

Problem: i am trying to store tile data for my map class. i had the idea of using a palette per layer, the palette would describe the data in the layer which would be an array of bytes with each byte representing a tile type.

this means 1 layer of 100 million tiles would equal ~96mb. however i overlooked how much data i could actually store in a byte and it turns out i can only store 256 tiles of course. resulting in square-root of 256 * tile-size texture sizes ( in this case 256 as tile sizes are 16) . 256*256 texture sizes are too small as each palette can only have one texture. severely limiting the tiles i can have in a layer.

i am now stuck in a bind as if i use 2 bytes ( short ) instead of 1 byte to store tile data i will double my memory usage to ~192mb per layer. and i want 4 layers at the minimum. inflating the end product to 768mb of ram used. i also can not describe the data in the data as the array offset of each byte is also a description of its location.

is there a way i could store this data more efficiently. worst case scenario will involve me saving all this to the disk and buffering to memory from the disk. but i would prefer to keep it in memory.

i guess i could come up with something smart in a few hours but i thought i would ask to see if there are any common methods i am unaware of to combat this problem.

Comment: This is the sort of problem that can be solved with your wallet. Buy more RAM. ;)

Comment: i suppose i am thinking a little old school a 2d game with 1gb ram requirements isnt that bad i suppose. still i would love an alternative.

Comment: I was sort of kidding, even if it would work. Are all the 100 million tiles visible at the same time? Otherwise, you could try to just keep the visible parts in memory, and load others as needed. Also, are all positions always containing data? Otherwise, look into creating a sparse structure.

Comment: no only the screen is visible so (screenwidth*height) /16 but if the user clicks on the minimap they can instantly change to any point in the map. so it needs fast loading. and yes all positions contain data.

Comment: So what's the purpose of the data? Which operations are you going to do on it? Just read it and display it? Or will you be editing it? And how many will you be using at a time (say withing couple of seconds)?

Comment: Than I suggest creating an external hash or tree or something. Something that will allow you to quickly fetch one block from file.

Comment: the data is a tilemap. it gets generated first and then after it is generated it only gets displayed.

Comment: i guess i will go with a memory mapped file then. 800mb is pretty insignificant these days.

Comment: Can you divide up your data into many smaller areas where each area only uses a small subset of the tiles so could use a single byte. And Different areas would use a different subset of the tiles? If this is for a map and each area has a theme, this might work?

Comment: i thought about that. but even with each area having a theme 256 tiles is quite limiting. i think i will go with the large file. thanks.

Comment: Wait a second. You really want to have a map of hundred million tiles? Even if your tiles are 4x4 pixels, on a screen of 1600x1200 it will still be 25x33 screens. Are you sure the player will be able to find that way around such huge map? And you won't draw anything meaningful on 4x4 (or did you mean 16x16). On modern, high-dpi monitor any meaningful object must be at least 32x32. 16x16 is up at 100x126 screens already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest representing your data in an array which maps to the two dimensional plane using a space filling curve such as the [Hilbert curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve).

Then, compress this using a combination of [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) and [run-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). This will be particularly effective if you data is often repeated locally (i.e. there are lots of sections which are all the same tile next to each other).

Do this compression in blocks of say 256 tiles. Then, have an array of offsets that indicate how far into the compressed data certain bytes numbers are.

For example, the start of the second block (tile 256) byte might be at position 103, and the start of the third block (tile 512) might be at position 192.

Then say to access the 400th tile, you can work out this is from the second block, so decompress the second block (in this case from byte 103 to byte 191) and from this get the 400 - 256 = 144 tile. Save (cache) this decompressed data for the moment, it's likely if you're getting nearby tiles they'll also be in this decompressed block. Perhaps in your array of offsets you should also include what blocks have been recently cached, and where in the cache they are.

If you wanted to allow modifications, you'd probably have to change your data structure from one large array to a vector of vectors. Have an indicator for each vector whether it is compressed or not. When doing modifications, uncompress blocks and modify them, and recompress blocks the least recently modified blocks when memory is running out.

---

Or, you could just dump the whole structure to a file and [memory map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) the file. This is much simpler but may be slower depending on the compressibility of your data and your access patterns due to additional I/O.